# Splicing XML sections with Python's `xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse`

Tags: python, xml

I would like to use `xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse()` to grab sections of an XML file. The file is 60GB and 1B lines, so I do not want to load it all into memory. I do not see a method for outputing whole subsections of xml in the `xml` library. I recognize that `iterparse` is iterative and probably only looks ahead so far. How can I do this?

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse

context = iterparse("file.xml", events=("start", "end"))

for event, elem in context:
    if event == 'start':
        if elem.tag == 'page':
            # Splice out this subset of the XML, including tags
            # Or, better, splice it if `<title>` includes "Foo".
    else:
        elem.clear()
```

The XML looks roughly like this:

```
<siteinfo>
    <page>
        <title>Foo</title>
            <text>Bar</text>
    </page>
    <page>
        <title>NotFoo</title>
        <text>NotBar</text>
    </page>
</siteinfo>
```

Comment: under `splice` you mean "remove" the node `<page>` or the whole `<siteinfo>`?

Comment: Everything from `<page>` to `</page>`, but preferably only where `<title>` is "Foo".

Answer (score 0):

i tried something, its not the exact output you expected, just sharing if it can be useful to you

```
path='D:\data.xml'
from xml.etree import ElementTree as Et

context = Et.iterparse(path,events=("start", "end"))
root = None
for event, elem in context:
    if event=='end' or event=='start':
        if elem.text=='Foo':
            elem.clear()
root=elem
with open('d:\output.xml', 'wb') as file:
    Et.ElementTree(root).write(file, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Output file :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<siteinfo>
    <page>
        **#some how this <title /> remains**
        ***<title />***
        <text>Bar</text>
    </page>
    <page>
        <title>NotFoo</title>
        <text>NotBar</text>
    </page>
</siteinfo>
```